# Twilio installed, failing with ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'twilio'

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I do a pip3 install Twilio, and see that:

```
Installing collected packages: twilio
Successfully installed twilio-8.1.0
```

I check in python and, do not see it:

```
$ sudo python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux

>>> import twilio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio'
```

Yet if we check in pip:

```
$ pip3 show twilio
Name: twilio
Version: 8.1.0
Summary: Twilio API client and TwiML generator
Home-page: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/
Author: Twilio
Author-email: help@twilio.com
License:
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, aiohttp-retry, PyJWT, pytz, requests
Required-by:
```

What else to try here?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
```

Answer (score 2):

`pip3` is pointing to a different version of python. Use `python -m pip install twilio` to fix this (or maybe `python3 -m pip install` for your case). Do not use `pip3 install` or `pip install` because these are ambiguous and can point to any python installation on your system.

You can check to see which installation `pip`, `pip3`, etc are pointing to by comparing:

```bash
python3 -m pip -V

python -m pip -V

pip3 -V

pip -V
```